# Common phrases for something that appears good but is actually bad

Tags: phrase-requests

What are common phrases that describe something that appears good but is actually bad?

Edit: Because people say *bad* is vague I will try to sum up the phrase meaning a little better.

- something that looks like it will be helpful or advantageous but after use it is hindering
- a tool that seems useful but is not the correct tool for the job
- something that seems like a good idea but after execution turns out to be problematic

Comment: For some reason I cannot post an answer. It seems that word fallacy could be suitable.

Comment: I can't help but think that the fact that this question has **26** answers is indicative that it is kind of problematic.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: I don't think it is problematic. the thing is, the person is looking for metaphors and there must be at least dozens of it. Usually one person doesn't know all of them, so each person gives as answer one of their own. It is impossible to get a single right answer to this (although it is possible to get many wrong answers)

Comment: @Tames that sounds an awful lot like a problem to me.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: language problems are not like 1+1=2!

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: maybe you could share your opinion on this http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2731/should-we-consider-the-creation-of-a-se-exclusive-for-words-idiomatic-express

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A *[poisoned chalice](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/poisoned-chalice)* is *something which seems good when received but actually does great harm*.

Comment: How about a mirage?

Answer (score 29):

If you want a proverb, it could be "Not all that glitters is gold", although what is not good is not necessarily bad.
Perhaps a good expression could be "a wolf in sheep's skin", as this is exactly a bad thing disguised as good.

Comment: Can you use "wolf in a sheep's skin" for non-persons?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe "Trojan horse" could be more appropriate in this case. A related expression is "beware greeks bearing gifts".

Comment: @Jonas - certainly you can. The expression I've heard is "a wolf in sheep's clothing."

Comment: @Tames: I've sometimes used a variant of that, particularly when dealing with IT salespeople: _Beware of geeks bearing gifts_.

Comment: a pig in a poke ?

Comment: @jao: it looks like a good one!

Comment: @J.R.: lovely variation!

Comment: "Gilded" (referring to the "Gilded age")?

Answer (score 23):

The term that pops into my mind is ["Fool's gold"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrite), after the mineral Pyrite, which looks like gold, so deceives those on first inspection.

Answer (score 16):

The adjective [*specious*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/specious?q=specious) also has the meaning you requested.

> Misleading in appearance, especially misleadingly attractive

I know you asked for a phrase though.

Comment: Yeah, I think specious is probably the right answer.

Answer (score 11):

A *poisoned apple* or *poisonous apple* is a symbol of something that looks good on the outside but is actually harmful. It, of course, is from the fairy tale of [Snow White.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_White)

Comment: For your second example "the wrong tool for the job" is a fairly common phrase. It means that what you're trying to use is, in fact, a useful tool, but it's not the right one to use on this particular job. (The tool doesn't have to be literally a mechanical or hand tool.)

Answer (score 10):

*Devil in disguise* satisfies the 1st and 3rd bullet points. There also is *wolf in sheep's clothing.* They both mean the same thing.

Comment: In many cases, the relatedly devlish phrase, "the devil is in the details," could be appropriate.    For the second bullet point:  "That screwdriver appeared to be about the right size for what I needed.  Unfortunately, the devil is in the details and that metric screwdriver didn't fit my half inch screws."

Answer (score 7):

I've heard "*hollow bunny*" used, in reference to chocolate easter bunnies.

The term is sometimes used to describe something *[disappointing](http://blogs.smithsonianmag.com/food/2010/04/easter-candy-history-why-are-chocolate-bunnies-hollow/)* – something that doesn't live up to expectations.

(Maybe you were wanting something much worse than being merely *disappointing*, but *bad* is a rather vague word, so it's hard to know for sure. If that's the case, though, I'm sorry about this *hollow bunny* of an answer.)

Comment: I hate those damned things, along with cotton candy. Such a tease, they are!

Answer (score 6):

How about a [Trojan Horse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_Horse)? In computer science it refers to software that seems useful but in fact does harm. The original Trojan Horse also appeared to be a delightful gift for the city of Troy, but held secret Greek soldiers that snuck out and destroyed the city.

Answer (score 5):

[Pig in a Poke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_in_a_poke) or *Cat in a sack*

> The idioms pig in a poke and sell a pup (or buy a pup) refer to a
>   confidence trick originating in the Late Middle Ages, when meat was
>   scarce, but cats and dogs (puppies) were not

Comment: "bought a lemon" http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53509/why-lemon-for-a-faulty-or-defective-item

Answer (score 5):

The design of some items can be described as having "form over function".  That is, the form of the item is aesthetically pleasing but doesn't actually do its job very well.

Comment: your comment reminded me of the expression "white elephant"

Comment: I also use "for show, not for go" in this situation.

Answer (score 5):

I kind of hope that the questioner will edit the question to reflect the many possible answers, so here's my contribution: a phrase popular in the North-East of England:

```
All fur coat, and no knickers.
```

In other words, the person referred to is all show and no substance.

Comment: In Texas we say "All hat and no cattle."

Answer (score 4):

I like the answer "Poisoned Chalice", from @Jasper Loy above. You might also consider, when talking about a situation instead of a thing, "primrose path". A path or way that is pleasant to walk but leads to disaster.

Answer (score 4):

"Good from far but far from good". For example, see that beautiful girl over there with phenomenal legs? Look again, it's a man.

Comment: I've heard this one "Good from afar..."

Answer (score 4):

1. A tool that seems useful but is not the correct tool for the job
2. Something that seems like a good idea but after execution turns out to be problematic

I heard the expression "A gold shield", something that looks appealing but is not suitable for the task, gold being beautiful but soft and heavy, offering poor protection.

I would otherwise use the proverb, "if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail". Suggesting you need to have more tools or you'll constraint your perception of the task.

Answer (score 4):

A [chocolate teapot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teapot) - although they work fine if the walls are thick enough!

Comment: A common variant is "about as much use as a Chocolate fireguard". However, I avoided that phrase in my answer to this question, because I feel it's not really what the questioner is looking for.

Answer (score 4):

This may be a bit on the crude side, but a favorite of mine, that comes from Chinese, is "Shiny on the outside, just like donkey dung."

Answer (score 4):

Gilded Turd (vulgar)

Good from afar, but far from good.  (In relation to a snazzy car on the lot, which on closer inspection turns out to be a dud.)

I also like song title "She ain't pretty, she just looks that way."  Which is similar to "Beauty is only skin deep."

Answer (score 4):

People often describe things that do "more harm than good"

Answer (score 3):

I will rather say it as "Illusion"

Comment: you make the assumption that all illusions are bad, which is not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 3):

"No all that glitters is gold" - people sometimes chase after stuff because it looks like it's what they want, even when it isn't. Easily applicable to stuff like the "Cult of New" where people want the shiny new technology.

For furniture, you might use "rickety" to describe something that would break if you sat on it.

If you're talking just about tools, I suppose you could use "Golden Hammer". It means that you have a tool you like so much that you use it for everything.

"Thin Reed" - something that might seem sturdy, but would break if leaned on it.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for some variant of *'Promised so much, delivered so little'*.

Answer (score 3):

`Pandora's Box, A Can of Worms` or `All Hell Breaks Loose` are examples of this in my opinion... each can be good in it's own sense to certain people... E.g. Pandora, a Fisherman and a Satanic Believer.

If you are looking for a more general term someone with `anterior motives` is someone who acts one way but has something else planned. `Two Faced` is also another way of saying this.

`Wolf in sheep's clothing` is also a nicer ways of articulating this.

See http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-proverbs.html

Comment: "Pandora's Box", "A Can of Worm", and "All Hell Breaks Loose" have nothing to do with something that appears good at first but turns out not to be good.

Comment: If you were Pandora, the box would be good at first same with the can of worms for a Fisherman... each statement has a context with an equal and opposite position via the context of its use.

Comment: "All hell breaks loose" in particular means something completely different...

Comment: @Jay: if you're a fisherman that can of worms appears just as good or bad whether you've opened it or not. And the idiomatic phrase "a can of worms" has nothing to do with something that seemed like a good idea at the time but isn't now. Nor does the allusion of Pandora's Box.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 How about eating very spicy, very greasy chorizo on the way in to work?

Answer (score 3):

ًit's just like *trusting a mirage* or simply a *mirage*.

Answer (score 2):

I like the word "Embellished"

[Embellished](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/embellished)

I know you asked for a phrase, but I thought I'd drop my own two cents in.

Answer (score 2):

"Apparent beauty is often deceptive"

What appears beautiful apparently, MAY NOT be beautiful. This states a strong possibility of not being beautiful but does not state that this is the case, always.

Answer (score 2):

> something that appears good but are actually bad

"The Only Free Cheese is in the Mousetrap", perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

There's `wonderclout`: "something that looks good on the outside but proves to be utterly worthless".

Note: This isn't a word in common usage today; very few people would know what you meant if you used it.  I just shared this for those interested in lexicography.

References:

- [Susie Dent (UK lexicographer & TV personality)](https://twitter.com/susie_dent/status/1250737827547054080)
- [Word Blog](https://prettygoodword.livejournal.com/192626.html)

Comment: A marvellous word, but (and the request for a 'phrase' can be overlooked, I feel) **_common?_**

Comment: Good point - added a note on my answer to clarify that this isn't a common word; thanks :)