# "Appear" instead of "look" in compounds (good appearing, cheesy appearing, etc.)

Tags: word-usage, collocation

As far as your English variety goes, is it OK to substitute "appearing" for "looking" in compounds without altering the meaning?

> ... *for a business to want **good appearing**, well dressed, healthy workers*...
>   [source](http://grammar.about.com/od/grammarfaq/a/What-Was-Good-English-A-Century-Ago.htm)
>
> *Passersby then began to comment on the **nice appearing** patterns*... [source](http://www.courierherald.com/lifestyle/223044151.html?mobile=true)
>
> *It is **good appearing**, not far too bouncing*... [source](http://goarticles.com/article/Car-Assessment-Peugeot-5007-1.8-Premium/6792333/)

Comment: It's not a good idea to do this, at least in American English, unless you want to have confused/bemused readers. *Appearing* in this sense might make the reader think that the subject wasn't there, or was invisible, and then suddenly appeared in a good or nice way. I would use **good-looking**.

Comment: The first quote seems to be from a source a century old, so I would not assume it's English is in style or content still fully acceptable to the modern ear.

Comment: @TylerH Can't "good appearing" be perceived as "having a good appearance" rather than "making a sudden appearance"?

Comment: If you say "he looked good", the meaning is unambiguous. If you say "he appeared good", it's not clear to me what it means. Maybe [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71398/common-phrases-for-something-that-appears-good-but-is-actually-bad).

Comment: 'Well presented' is probably what you want instead of 'good appearing'.

Comment: _Look-ing_ is the current idiom; _appear_ has other connotations and quite different grammar. _Look_ is one of the [sense verbs with its own special syntax and semantics](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299), while _appear_ is mostly used metaphorically to mean _seem_ and syntactically it's an [A-Raising verb](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf), also like _seem_.

Comment: _appearing_ is often used when describing surface qualities that don't match the underlying quality. So _good appearing_ suggests someone who seems to be good, but actually isn't.

Comment: That third link, the author is not a native speaker, he's good but his mistakes are typical of advanced ESL speakers.

Comment: The second, I would argue, the author meant to say: *Passersby then began to comment on the nice patterns **appearing** on the velvet-like lawn*

Answer (score 2):

This is called [collocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation) and is highly language specific
Basically, it's the proper combination of words for use in a sentence (example, adjective for particular noun+particular noun) and will appear strange to a native speaker if used wrongly, although might appear to have the same meaning to non-native speakers
This is something a non-native speaker will have to learn through practice

Further readings:
http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/easy/colloc.htm

> I want to concentrate in this article on the problems non-native
>   speakers may have with English vocabulary use - in particular with the
>   appropriate combinations of words. This is an aspect of language
>   called collocation. An example of collocation that many learners of
>   English may be familiar with is the different adjectives that are used
>   to describe a good-looking man and a good-looking woman. We talk of a
>   beautiful woman and of a handsome man, but rarely of a beautiful man
>   or a handsome woman.
>
> > . . . .
> >     In another familiar example of collocation, we talk of high mountains
> >     and tall trees, but not usually of tall mountains and high trees.

[http://www.norbertschmitt.co.uk/uploads/durrant-p-and-schmitt-n-(2009)-to-what-extent-do-native-and-nonnative-writers-make-use-of-collocations-international-review-of-applied-linguistics-47-157-177.pdf](http://www.norbertschmitt.co.uk/uploads/durrant-p-and-schmitt-n-%282009%29-to-what-extent-do-native-and-nonnative-writers-make-use-of-collocations-international-review-of-applied-linguistics-47-157-177.pdf)

Or search collocation on Google