# Why does "lemon" mean "inferior"?

Tags: etymology, word-usage

Please see [this example](http://www.fountainpennetwork.com/forum/index.php/topic/108031-aurora-ipsilon-review/#entry1089354). The poster uses the word *lemon* in the last sentence. I understand in a general sense that this is being used to indicate something bad or more specifically of inferior quality.

Indeed, Roget's Thesaurus [shows the following  synonyms for lemon](http://thesaurus.com/browse/lemon): *failure*, *flop*, *junk*, *reject*, and *piece of junk*.

It will be interesting to know how *lemon* came to mean an inferior quality.

As shown [here](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=lemon&allowed_in_frame=0), it might have something to do with "sucking the juice out of somebody" or "bad taste left in mouth."

This seems contradictory to me since [lemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon) is fruit with great nutritional,
medicinal and culinary value. Moreover, there are so many fruits out of which you suck the juice out. And lemon taste is never bad.

Comment: Good news! This has already been answered here: [Why "lemon" for a faulty or defective item?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53509/why-lemon-for-a-faulty-or-defective-item)

Answer (score 1):

I think the primary derivation is most likely to be connected with the British slang usage indicated at the etymonline link you've cited:  "to hand someone a lemon".  The image is of being given something expecting it to be sweet, and then biting into it and finding it to be very sour.  You say that the taste of a lemon is never bad, but I wonder; do you really enjoy biting into lemons?

Comment: Well, directly biting a lemon is never my favorite, compared to oranges or mangoes or strawberries,   but, putting lemon juice in some food items really make them taste better.