# How to name a tenant that needs/doesn't need maintenance work from landlord side?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I found the question titled [Word for something needing maintenance](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/319935/word-for-something-needing-maintenance) but it does not answer my question.

To elaborate, some tenants call very often to landlord or property manager, asking them to come in and screw in light bulbs, change the toilet seat because it broke, etc., while the other tenants are screwing in these light bulbs and fixing toilet seats themselves. The first ones need maintenance, and the second ones don't need maintenance from landlord side.

Question is, what is the name of the first ones and the second ones?

Google translator returned me, for that word in my language, the word *maintenance-free* for the second ones, but could a tenant be maintenance-free for landlord?

Comment: The tenancy agreement should make clear the [**obligations**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/obligation) and [**responsibilities**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/responsibility) of each party although the adjectival forms would be a bit clumsy.

Comment: Following the edit, 'maintenance-free' usually means that something does not *need* maintenance (such as a sealed battery), it's not about who should do it.

Comment: I agree what @wheather says, but at least in the US, you could informally describe a tenant as "low-maintenance" or "maintenance-free"

Comment: True, *people* can be described as 'high-maintenance' too.

Comment: Could it be self-reliant tenant and not self-reliant tenant? The quality of it would be "self-reliance", so how self-reliant tenant is?

Comment: I believe that _all_ tenants would need the landlord to fix some things. You wouldn't want tenants repairing burst water pipes, damaged wiring or broken window frames even if they had the skills.

Comment: @BoldBen Thanks for insight, but question here is about language advice, not about business advice

Comment: @ToTenMilan I was concerned that your question implied that the tenant did not need _any_ maintenance services from the landlord. It would have been better phrased as "What would be the term for a tenant who requires a lot of maintenance input from the landlord or one who sees to small repairs himself?" The latter could be described as **self reliant**.